# Is there a way to make 7zip temporarly uncompress the whole archive when double-clicking on an exe?

Tags: windows, 7-zip

In WinRAR, one feature which I like is the fact that you can set it to uncompress the whole archive in a temporary place, if you double-click on an .exe file **inside the archive opened in WinRAR**.

Typically, I often download small games, which I just want to try, without the hassle of creating a folder for it, etc. Same for archives containing an installer with its own separate files.

In the 7-zip window, if I double-click an exe, it will just extract the exe in a temporary location and launch it. In the small game context (or installer), it means that it will simply fail, because it will miss required files in the same folder.

So my question is: **Is there a way to make 7-zip extract the whole archive in a temporary folder when launching an exe from inside the archive?**

Comment: Why can't you just manually extract that whole thing to a temp location manually, then run it...

Comment: @soandos - because the point of my question is precisely to have the program do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 7zip, so I explain using WinRar:

Simply create a batch file named unrar.bat

```
c:
md \unrar
cd \unrar
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\unrar.exe" e %1
start c:\unrar
```

Now right click any .rar file and choose Open with... Browse that unrar.bat

I hope you see the idea.

P.S: You can create a shotcut at taskbar/quicklaunch and then drag files over the icon of .bat file -instead of right clicking...

Comment: Interesting workaround, but not really what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can not do what you want since you doubleclick the exe file, the executable files just run & process that what it coded for. The only solution is configuring 7zip, if it allows what you want.

Comment: my question is exactly about how to make 7zip do that. I'm not used to the program, I don't really know of plugins or settings.

Comment: A few programs can sense the self-executable compressed files and uncompress them. Right-click it and try to unzip/unrar. Winrar can do that too. If so, you can unzip the .exe file like regular .zip/7z files... Just try.

Comment: Just realized that my question could be misunderstood, in fact. What I'm talking about is to double-click an exe file inside the archive (which would be a regular zip file, for example), with the archive opened already in 7-zip. Sorry about the confusion, I forgot about exe which are just self-extracting archives.